# Is it possible to use SWIG to wrap static libraries with .a extension?

Tags: c, android-ndk, swig

I compiled a C project using the NDK and got many .a files which as I understand, they are nothing else than static libraries. I don't know exactly what is the difference between .a and .so files but I wanted to ask: I know exactly that with a toolchain in NDK I can import all the .a files and get the .so file but having the .a files how to include the .a files in the .interface files to SWIG the whole library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWIG does not generate interface files from libraries. You can provide a wrapper to include all relevant header (`.h`) files, or create the `.i` file manually, only exposing the relevant `C` functions.

Note that Android app cannot work with static libraries, you *must* build a dynamic library `.so` to use JNI. You will call `System.load()` from your Java code to load this `.so` from disk.